# Cycle between minimized windows while preserving position

Tags: awesome-wm

So I have this keybind:

```lua
  awful.key({modkey}, ";",
    function()
      if client.focus then
        for c in awful.client.iterate(function(x) return x.minimized end) do
          c.minimized = false
          client.focus.minimized = true
          client.focus = c
          client.focus:raise()
          break
        end
      end
    end
```

The aim is to swap the focused client with the first minimized client, but not a simple cycle as I want it to be agnostic to how many un-minimized clients there are on screen. It works as intended, except that the positioning of the client on the screen isn't preserved. From what I can tell, if the newly un-minimized & focused client has a higer index than the next highest un-minimized client, then it will always end up positioned after it on the screen, and I have no idea how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

While it does nothing to clarify the issue I was running into, here's the workaround I came up with to accomplish the goal I had in mind:

```lua
if client.focus then
  local c = client.focus
  local nxt = nil
  for x in awful.client.iterate(function(x) return x.minimized end) do
    if nxt then nxt:swap(x) else nxt = x end
  end
  c.minimized = true
  nxt.minimized = false
  c:swap(nxt)
  client.focus = nxt
end
```

I decided to do away with keeping the clients in their original order, and instead, any x of un-minimized clients will occupy positions 1-x in the clients table, while any minimized clients will form a queue along the remaining positions. Conveniently, spawning a new client gives it focus, makes it a master, and puts it in the first position, so the ordering is maintained.

It works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Just kidding, the iterator won't restrict to a single tag, so it doesn't work.